# Count number of employees that earn more than x value and less than x value by city

Tags: sql, oracle

Table is named ***employee*** and columns are ***city***,  ***salary*** and ***employee***

goal : in a single query , to count all the employees that earn >=1300 value  less than <=1300  by city.

| city | stipendio | employee |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Milano | 1200 | employee1 |
| Roma | 1000 | employee2 |
| Milano | 2000 | employee3 |
| Roma | 900 | employee4 |
| Milano | 1600 | employee5 |

Query I did separately :

#1

```
select
CITTA,
COUNT(*)
FROM
employee
WHERE city in ( 'Milano', 'Roma')
and salary>=1300 
GROUP BY city;
```

#2

```
select
city,
COUNT(*)
FROM
employee
WHERE city in ( 'Milano', 'Roma')
and salary<=1300
GROUP BY city;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation.  That is, include `CASE` expressions inside the aggregate.

```
SELECT
  city,
  SUM(CASE WHEN salary <= 1300 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  less_than_or_equal_to,
  SUM(CASE WHEN salary >  1300 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  greater_than
FROM
  employee
WHERE
  city IN ( 'Milano', 'Roma')
GROUP BY
  city;
```

Comment: thank you! im new in sql and i've learned a new method

Comment: The sample data only shows cities 'Milano' and 'Roma'.  But suppose there are others in the table?  I'd think, based on the stated requirement, that the specific city is actually irrelevent, and so the WHERE CITY IN .. should be removed.

Comment: @EdStevens - To quote the OP...  "I did it in separately: #1 #2" - With both those queries including the `WHERE` clause.  If it's in the question, it's going in my answer ;)

Comment: @MatBailie, if someone asks how to shoot themselves in the foot, I would not just blindly tell them how to do so.  People quite often ask the wrong question to solve their problem.  See https://xyproblem.info/   I'm more about educating people than I am just giving canned answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
select
city,
sum(case when salary<=1300 then 1 else 0 end) below,
sum(case when salary>1300 then 1 else 0 end) above


 from employee

WHERE city in ( 'Milano', 'Roma')
group by city
```

Comment: thank you! it was similar to who previously answered but it worked the same and very well, i got the result i wanted :)